# Combine three raster images into one raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I have three raster images within a similar region

[image]

I'd like to combine these three rasters into one raster image using QGIS or any other open-source method, and where there are gaps just set as a nodata value.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try QGIS with `Menu raster > Miscellaneous > Merge` or `Build Virtual Raster`?

Comment: I've tried both and keep getting this error ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"C:/Users/Amy/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_JazlHT/47c0fba9c2bc48d08f0f007800ddb36a/buildvrtInputFiles.txt"```

Comment: you should provide more details about what exactly you did. Please edit you initial  question to add details, the comments here are just for clarifications

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have difficulties merging files with the merge algorithm when:

- files are not tiff files, converting to tiff first could help
- files do not include projection, converting to tiff first with projection could help